# psql uppercase backreferenced string in regexp_replace

Tags: regex, uppercase, psql, backreference

I have a string, that was previously processed with initcap(), and I wanto to uppercase part of it.

To be specific - I want to uppercase basic roman digits that might occur.

To be even more specific I'd like to replace

> Jana Iii Sobieskiego

to

> Jana III Sobieskiego

I suppose I could use some kind of a upper-substring-subquery combo to achieve it, but I am trying to make it work in a single regexp_replace, like this:

```
SELECT 
  ulica
  --, regexp_matches(ulica , '((^|\s)([XxIiVv]+)(\s|$))', 'g')
  , regexp_replace(ulica, '((^|\s)([XxIiVv]+)(\s|$))', '\2'||upper('q\3q')||'\4' , 'g') 
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(ARRAY['Jana Iii Sobieskiego', 'Xx Lecia', 'Xxx Lecia Panowania Zygmunta Iii Wazy'])::text AS ulica
) AS src
```

What happens, is that upper works on the 'static' part of replacement string (q...q), but not on the backreference.

I get

> Jana QIiiQ Sobieskiego

Anyone has an idea how to do this?

**PostgreSQL 9.1**

Comment: How did you solve this? at this moment I'm gonna do a workaround. Sorry @Stephan for not confirming your answer for me it was just easier to accept lower cases in my system

Comment: I didn't. Seems that it can't be done.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! it's good for posteriority. I wonder if that changed in recent versions of Postgres. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER**
Unfortunately, what you have tried is not possible with `regexp_replace`.

**LONG ANSWER**
***INTRO***
This line

```
regexp_replace(ulica, '((^|\s)([XxIiVv]+)(\s|$))', '\2'||upper('q\3q')||'\4' , 'g')
```

is equivalent to

```
regexp_replace(ulica, '((^|\s)([XxIiVv]+)(\s|$))', '\2Q\3Q\4' , 'g')
```

As you can see, `regexp_replace` won't upper case any backreferences.

***WORKAROUND***
You can create your own function that take an `ulica` as parameter and returns `ulica` with basic roman digits uppercased.

- **Step 1**
  In a first step this function would mark (I choose `$$` as a marker but you can use any.) the part of ulica to be uppercased like this:

```
    regexp_replace(ulica, '((^|\s)([XxIiVv]+)(\s|$))', '\2$$\3$$\4' , 'g')
```

- **Step 2**
  In a second step, go through the resulting string and uppercase each char located between two markers.